# What does SLA mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In the Bibliography at the end of the first chapter of "Beautiful Shadow: Life of Patricia Highsmith" by Andrew Wilson is said, "PH, Cahier 19, SLA." What does an abbreviation SLA mean?

Comment: The book should have  (does have) a list of abbreviations used in the book. For example, "AK" could be the Alfred A. Knopf Archive. The abbreviations could be idiosyncratic, not standard. *Swiss Literary Archives, Berne*.

Answer (score 1):

**"PH, Cahier 19, SLA."** stands for *Patricia Highsmith, Highsmith's journal #19, [Swiss Literary Archives](https://www.revolvy.com/topic/Swiss%20Literary%20Archives&uid=1575).*

**Patricia Highsmith** called the Highsmith's journals **[cahiers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1408811197)**[image]